# How to add different text color to bitmap image?

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap

How to add different text with different colour in bitmap image using wpf.i have written the code it will take only one colour in text line but i want different colour in bitmap

```
SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.White);
System.Drawing.Brush brush1 = new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Blue);
// draw your rectangle below the original image
System.Drawing.Font font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", fontsize, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
SizeF textSize = new SizeF();
graphics.DrawString(multiLineString, font, brush1, position);
```

please help me out from this problem

Comment: Your question looks quite unclear. You have created brush having blue color and use this brush to draw your string - so what does "*but i want different colour*" mean? Create another brush with another color if you want and use it for drawing.

Comment: k but i want for ex the string is "i am going to home" k now i want "i am" is blue color and "going" red colour and "home " is green i want to add this line to image

Comment: You have to draw the strings separately by using different brushes. To find out on what pixel positions you have to put the elements you can use the TextRenderer to get a rectangle with the needed size.

Comment: @user3535705  I think this is a WinForms question, not WPF so you might want to edit your tags. That said, you probably just want to vary the `position` value before you draw each differently coloured string (ie. draw the blue text, then change the position and draw the red text, and so on). From memory there are methods on the `Graphics` class to measure the width of a text string.

Comment: Another apporach would be the usage of a LinearGradientBrush, but you still would need the TextRenderer to find out on which positions to put which colors.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment - you just need following:

- create all the brushes you need - having red, blue and green colors;
- split your source string into "i am", "going" and "home" strings;
- calculate width in pixels of each string using font you've created and [Graphics.MeasureString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.measurestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method;
- draw first string from your source position using red brush;
- increment position X coordinate with first string width in pixels
- draw the rest of your strings using brushes you want in the same manner.